# How to read a delimited file using Spark RDD, if the actual data is embedded with same delimiter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to read a text  file into an rdd

My sample data is below

```
"1" "Hai    How are you!"   "56"
"2"                         "0213"
```

3 columns with Tab delimiter. My data is also getting embedded with same delimiter(How\tHow areyou!).  Can some one help me here to parse the data properly in pyspark.

```
my_Rdd = Spark.SparkContext.textFile("Mytext.txt").map(lambda line:line.split('\t'))
```

When I do the above code I get below output

```
ColA,ColB,Colc
"1","Hai,How are you!"
"2","0123"
```

2nd column splitted to 3rd as it is having the same delimiter in actual data and for 2nd row the 3rd value is getting mapped to 2nd

My expected output is

```
ColA,ColB,Colc
"1","Hai    How are you!","56"
"2",,"0123"
```

In Dataframe I can keep quote options, but how can we do the same in RDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shlex.split()` which ignores quoted delimiters:

```
import shlex

sc.textFile('Mytext.txt').map(lambda line: shlex.split(line))
```

Another example with string:

```
import shlex

rdd = sc.parallelize(['"1"\t"Hai\tHow are you!"\t"56"']).map(lambda line: shlex.split(line))

>>> rdd.collect()
[['1', 'Hai\tHow are you!', '56']]
```

Comment: Dont we need to give \t delimiter anywhere?When I tried this snippet, I am getting empty RDD

Comment: shlex splits by any white-space like characters, so it splits on `\t` as well. I don't understand why you got empty RDD. I tested this with the text file you provided.

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni please test with the second code snippet?

Comment: Yup. I tried it is working now, But when I tried with actual data it is breaking,I have a combination of data with quote and without quote. without quotes it is not working as expected. I have edited my question.

Comment: is it okay to use `spark.read.csv('Mytext.txt', sep='\t').rdd`? I mean, it's possible to parse it by hand, but why reinvent the wheel when there are tools available from spark already.